# Why does line 1 print [1,2,3,"a"], and not just [1,2,3]? is it because of the L2=f2(L1,'a')? HOW?

Tags: python

```
def f1(v,y):
      v = 4
      y += v
      return y

def f2(L,x):
    L.append(x)
    return L
L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = `f2(L1,'a')`
print(L1)    # Line 1
print(L2)    # Line 2
a = 2
b = 3
c = f1(a,b)
print(a)     # Line 3
print(c)     # Line 4
print( f1(L1,1) )  # Line 5
```

Why does line 1 print [1,2,3,"a"], and not just [1,2,3]?
Is it because of the L2=f2(L1,'a')? HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because, while passing the argument `L1` to function `f2`, pointer of a variable is passed. Therefore, when you append a value to variable `L` inside your function, the list `L1` is also modified(`L` is nothing but a pointer to `L1`)

> if a function modifies an object passed as an argument, the caller
>   will see the change

Take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects)

Therefore `is it beacuse of the L2=f2(L1,'a')?` **yes**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

`f2` appends the second argument to the list passed as the first argument. Appending `"a"` to `[1, 2, 3]` will produce the output of `[1, 2, 3, "a"]` you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If want to get L1 as [1,2,3] then assign it to new list...

```
def f2(L,x):
    L3 = L.copy()  # copy passed list 'L' to L3
    L3.append(x)
    return L3 # return list with x at end of list
```

But this won't change your current list L1

Answer (score 0):

Let L = [1,2,3].
you want to append 'a' in this list 
like this,L.append('a')
then list will be L = [1,2,3,'a']. R8?
Same thing happen here using a function f2(L,'a')
f2 function takes a list and a value 'a' as a parameter and append 'a' into L list then return L with value [1,2,3,'a'].
and this list is assigned to a variable called L2.